# Proxymesh proxies returning 408 status code

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am using proxymesh proxies to crawl different websites. Suddenly it start sending status 408.

Here is log,

```
Retrying <GET http://www.toysrus.com/product/index.jsp?productId=23046326&cp=&parentPage=search> (failed 1 times): 408 Request Time-out
```

Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really used proxymesh myself, but there are some things you should do:

1. You need to confirm that it isn't a site problem, so going to the site to check if it is also returning a 408 status (or maybe just being down).
2. The site (and proxymesh) could actually need more time to complete the request, for which according to [proxymesh documentation](https://proxymesh.com/blog/pages/proxy-server-headers.html) could be increased by sending the `X-ProxyMesh-Timeout` header.
3. Check if proxymesh is returning more information (not just 408 status) in the response or headers. If you are using scrapy, check the [Retrying settings](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry) and you could handle bad statuses with `errback` method.

Comment: Actually, i found most of there IP's are banned by remote site.

Comment: yeah that information usually comes in the response body or headers